# Direct formula for a variation of Josephus problem:

Tags: contest-math

What is the direct formula for the following variation of Josephus problem?

> There are $n$ persons, numbered $1$ to $n$, around a circle.. Starting from $k$-th person, every second person is eliminated. Given the $n$ and $k$, determine the index of the $x$-th person who is eliminated.

ADDED:In the first step the $k+1$th is eliminated.For n = 16,k = 6, elimination={7,9,...}

Thanks

Comment: Is number $k$ the first to be eliminated, or is it $k+2$?  In any case,  this just rotates the circle by $k-1$ or $k+1$ postions

Comment: @Ross Millikan:Could you please explain,I did not understand your second point.

Comment: Just that you can eliminate the dependence on k by renumbering the people, then add back in the k after you have solved the problem.  So if there are 10 people and you start counting with 1, the sixth one eliminated is number 3 and the seventh is 7.  So if you first eliminate 7 (instead of 2) the sixth one eliminated will be $3+5 \pmod {10}=8$ and the seventh will be $7+5 \pmod {10}=2$

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [the Wikipedia page,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) there is [a reference](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~shamsbaa/Josephus.pdf) at the bottom

Answer (score -1):

I made a video very closely related to this question. There's a link to the video at: http://oeis.org/A006165